# Migrating LibGDX project to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

I have bought a new Laptop with higher configuration and I am in the process of moving my existing plain android and LibGDX based android project to my new Laptop. Since Google stopped the support for eclipse, I planned to move to Android studio in my new Laptop.

I am done migrating my plain android projects to Android studio. I am not clear about the process for migrating the LibGDX projects to Android studio. Hence I have the following questions.

1. Do I need to use the import plugin from Android studio ?
2. Do I need to create the similar LibGDX project and copy the source files ?
3. If I create a new project and copy source file will the old keystore work ?
4. Could you please list me the steps for a successful migration of LibGDX project to Android Studio ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just import the projects as Gradle projects.

Comment: if so, what about the core project from libgdx

Comment: You will import all projects.

Comment: And yes, the old keystore will work.